# Connection between compactly supported smooth functions on a bounded domain and sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces, smooth-functions

I am interested in finding a direct yes or no answer for the following:

In general, on a bounded domain $\Omega$ in $R^n$ with say $C^1$ boundary, can we that say any function $f$ $\in$ $C_c^{\infty}$($\Omega$), where $C_c^{\infty}$($\Omega$) is the space of all compactly supported smooth functions defined on $\Omega$, must also belong to a sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, for $1 \le p < \infty$?

I appreciate anyone's help, and enlightenment. If not can someone please give an example?

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the case. You can show that for any $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open and any $k \in \mathbb N$, $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ the inclusion $C_c^\infty \subset W^{k,p}$ holds true. First acknowledge that the case $k=0$ is trivial. Then convince yourself that the case $k=1$ contains all the difficulty. Now to see this for $k=1$ let $u,\varphi \in C_c^\infty$, pick $i = 1,...,n$, you want to find $v \in L^p$ such that
$$
\int_\Omega u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i} = - \int_\Omega v \varphi.
$$
If life was good then $v = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$ the classical partial derivative would be ok. And indeed that's the case, you can first observe
$$
\int_\Omega u \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i} + \int_\Omega \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \varphi = \int_\Omega \frac{\partial (u\varphi)}{\partial x_i}.
$$
At this point either you know integration by part (Gauss Green formula, divergence theorem or Stokes formula) or you can show by basic real analysis that
$$
\forall \psi \in C^1_c(\Omega),\quad \int_\Omega \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_i} = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks @blamethelag for your helpful response! very clean answer. Intuitively speaking for a given compactly supported smooth function on $\Omega$, any order derivative has to be bounded, and bounded functions on a compact domain belong to Lp. The smoothness of the function allows for existence of strong derivatives everywhere. Does that reasoning sound well too?

Comment: @sandykuks Yes that reasoning is good for showing that all derivatives of $f$ are in $L^p$.

Comment: @sandykuks yes that's the spirit : being regular they  have a candidate for the weak derivative and being compactly supported continuous the candidate is in any $L^p$. Another point : you can find mild conditions to get $C^1(\overline{\Omega}) \subset W^{1,p} (\Omega)$ but find an analytic function (say on the unit ball) that is $L^\infty$ but not $W^{1,1}$. This may help you to bear in mind that being smooth is not enough.

Comment: @ Kakashi - Thanks.  @blamethelag many thanks for your derivation and comments too. To your point, $f$ $\in$ $L^{\infty}$ but not in $W^{1,1}$ seems plausible, since there is nothing to control the norm of the first derivative, although the first derivative exists, its Lp norm can get unbounded. I think the case you are pointing out, is certainly interesting, but very different from compactly supported smooth functions on bounded domain being in $W^{k,p}$, no?

Comment: Do you know an analytic function that has compact support?

Comment: Yup, am aware, I meant the reason for function in $L^{\infty}$ and not being in $W^{1,1}$, or in general not bounded existing all derivatives in general differs in nature than the condition of compactly supported smooth function causing function to be in $W^{k,p}$. Cheers.